# Find a utility function for a specific problem

Tags: utility

How can we find a **utility function** that represents buying a car that receive as an input $x,y, z$ when:

- $x$ - The color of the car - The most important thing when red is better than blue that better which is better than green.
- $y$ - Engine - The second most important thing - An electric vehicle is better than gasoline which is better than diesel.
- $z$ - Car manufacturer - The third most important thing - When German manufacturer is better than French which is better than British.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your requirement there is no unique way of setting the utility as far as I can see.

One alternative could be having the following utility:

$$U = x^\alpha y^\beta z^\gamma$$

Where $\alpha> \beta > \gamma$, next let $x=3$ if color is red, 2 if green, 1 if blue. Apply the logic to $y$ and $z$.

Comment: The OP seems to describe a lexicographic utility function: "*The most important thing* [...] *The second most important thing* [...]" This is not that. (Though given the limited input space the parameters could be set in such a way that it does become lexicographic.)

Comment: @Giskard that would maybe work even better but I think the above does job as well, I was just giving an simple example

Comment: @1muflon1 If the input space isn't limited, what should be the utility function?

Comment: @PedroGómez you could use the same function with i =1,2,3 ... n to order the unlimited set of possible inputs or you can follow the giskards suggestion

Comment: @1muflon1 My suggestion is not constructive; I wrote that you did not answer the question, which seems to have been about lexicographic preferences, not Cobb-Douglas. It was indeed a mistake to write "*lexicographic utility function*" instead of "lexicographic preferences".